# ExpandableListView GroupView with an EditText Expanded not working

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, expandablelistview

I tried to keep edit text in group view of expandable listview.If i keep edit text Expanded and  collapse not working for the groupview.

I tried with other views like text view and check boxes group view working fine .

May you know what was the reason for expand and collapse not working with edittext.

**Sample wroking groupview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#8cae88"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
      android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="#f9f93d"
        android:textSize="17dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="SampleTxt"
        android:textColor="#f9f93d"
        android:textSize="17dp" />



</LinearLayout>
```

**Sample after adding edittext not wroking groupview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#8cae88"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
      android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="#f9f93d"
        android:textSize="17dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="SampleTxt"
        android:textColor="#f9f93d"
        android:textSize="17dp" />
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/b_discount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**Here is the ExpandableListAdapter getGroupView method code**

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
            }

            TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
            lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue_list_dashboard);
            return convertView;
        }
```

Thanks for advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working for the groupview"? can you please explain..

Comment: collpse and expand not working for the group

Comment: I guess this is because when you try to click on the expanded view then your text view is taking that click, But it should work by clicking on parent view.

Comment: @PratikGoyal can you please share that example.

Comment: @Surya Now I got the point you are using Edit text on the GroupView so yes it won't work as EditText will take the Focus, Because when I make EditText non focus-able it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Didn't able to find the solution. Tried all the things.
But what i did is :-

```
 <Linearlayout>  
    <edittext> (Gone)
</Linearlayout>
```

When user click on edittext just visible the edittext and put focus on edittext.
Just a kind of trick.

If any one have the best solution please come up. Because it not a good way. But its working.